# Are there bathtub spouts with diverter valves that don't drop when the water is turned off?

Tags: bathtub, diverter, spout

Are there bathtub spouts with diverters that stay closed when the water is turned off?

I just installed a new bathtub spout with diverter. My previous spout's diverter would stay closed when the water was turned off, due to age I guess. I realized this is a good function as I never take a bath and having to close the diverter everyday to take a shower is annoying.

Comment: Ah - a classic first-world problem! Pull it up and wrap some tape around the stem.

Comment: No reason for a down vote the question was asking if a product existed. Reversed.

Comment: cut a straw or clear tubing to the length of the stem rise, then slice a slit along the length, then apply to the stem to hold it up; waterproof, cheap, reversible.

Comment: I looked around and did not see a locking type diverter spigot. when searching I came across a post that mentioned how much longer it would take for the hot water to arrive, another mentioned a simple rubber band around the diverter to hold it up. There may be one out there as others are asking the same question but I did not find one with a quick search. @danDavis make that an answer it is better than the rubber band suggestion I saw.